# Writing to File Internal Storage Android

Tags: android, save, storage, internal

Given this code:

```
final String dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS) + "/";
    String file = dir + "info.txt";
    File newfile = new File(file);


        //Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()= /storage/emulated/0

String msgData="p1000";
        FileOutputStream outputStream;

        try {
            newfile.createNewFile();

            outputStream = openFileOutput(file, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            outputStream.write(msgData.getBytes());
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.toString();
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

When I open file /storage/emulated/0/Documents/info.text, I find it empty while it should have the string "p1000";

why is that?
note: I do not have external storage (external sd card).

thanks.

Comment: Instead of "e.toString()" you should have a proper exception logging in place, most likely there's an exception that you're just ignoring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE Permission in your Manifest?

Try this: FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

Comment: Your sample code shows you want to write to external not internal storage. So do you want to write to external or internal storage?

Comment: to internal but with specifying the path of saved file

Comment: Glad I could help.  Have fun Coding

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna use internal storage you should not pass a path pointing at the external storage (roughly sd card). In you try-catch block use this line instead:

```
outputStream = openFileOutput("info.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

The file will be saved in the directory returned by `Context.getFilesDir()`.

Comment: but I need info.txt in a specific path of my choice.

Comment: In android there is either internal or external storage. The first is mapped to "/data/data/my.app.pkg/" and cannot be changed. You can have multiple files in that dir. External storage is different: you need permissions to write it or read it. The main external storage directory can be retrieved with  Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(). You can choose a *specific path* in either of these two.